# Handle POST request data with Node js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, post

Is there any method to get the text contained by a paragraph using POST method in a form?
I whould like to get the text in the paragraph below:

```
<form id="selected_activity_form" method="POST" action=<%=token%>>
        <p>text_goes_here</p>
        <input type="submit" value="click" name="btn" id="btn"/>
</form>
```

P.S.
I'm using Node Js to handle the requests.

Comment: What does your server code look like?

Answer (score -1):

************************************************Example - 1*************************************

```
<form method="POST" action="/login">
   <input name="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
   <input name="password" placeholder="Password" />
</form>

const http = require('http'),
const qs = require('querystring');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST' && req.url === '/login') {
    var body = '';
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {
      body += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', function() {
      var data = qs.parse(body);

      //**** now you can access `data.email` and `data.password`********//

      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(404);
    res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(80);
```

*****************************Example - 2***********************

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>CSS3 Contact Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="contact">
    <h1>Send an email</h1>
    <form action="/myaction" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />

            <label for="email">Email:</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />

            <label for="message">Message:</label>
            <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>

            <input type="submit" value="Send message" />

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using http.createServer is very low-level and really not useful for creating web applications as-is.

A good framework to use on top of it is Express, and I would seriously suggest using it. You can install it using npm install express.

When you have, you can create a basic application to handle your form:

```
var express = require('express');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var app     = express();

    //Note that in version 4 of express, express.bodyParser() was
    //deprecated in favor of a separate 'body-parser' module.
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

    //app.use(express.bodyParser());

    app.post('/myaction', function(req, res) {
      res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
    });

    app.listen(8080, function() {
      console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/');
    });
```

You can make your form point to it using:

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:8080/myaction" method="post">
```

The reason you can't run Node on port 80 is because there's already a process running on that port (which is serving your index.html). You could use Express to also serve static content, like index.html, using the express.static middleware.